# Android Studio build types - exclude java sources from build?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-productflavors

I'm working on a huge application with a lot of features. I'm using build types in order to obtain apks with only one feature. In order to do this I need to exclude all resources that I don't need for those features, so the apks would be smaller than the big application. I managed to reduce the size of this apks by using proguard but it's not enough. There is some way I could exclude java classes and resources from the build?

I tried this [Android Studio Exclude Class from build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build)
but it's not working. I read here [Android Studio: Exclude resource file under resources sourceSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172731/android-studio-exclude-resource-file-under-resources-sourcesets) that it's not supported yet for Android sourceSets to exclude sources.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?