# Android Gradle - How to include assets from the root project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following project structure

```
MyProject
|-- build.gradle
|-- client.private
|-- server.public
|-- app
|   |-- build.gradle
|   |-- lint.xml
|   |-- proguard-project.txt
|   |-- project.properties
|   `-- src
```

and would like to include `client.private` and `server.public` files into the assets folder of the final apk but unfortunately not able to do so.

Have the following in my `app/build.gradle`

```
...
android {
    ...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
            copy {
              from(['../client.private', '../server.public'])
              into("${buildDir}/assets/${variant.dirName}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it only copies the files to `app/build/assets/debug`, its not packaged with the apk.

Comment: If your packaging the file into the `apk` then you can no longer consider it private.  Extracting a raw file from an `apk` is as trivial as renaming it to a `.zip` and decompressing the archive.

Comment: Yes, true. They are actually keystores containing private and public keys for a ssl socket connection. Unfortunately, I don't know a better way.

Comment: Get them from a server.  Have the client send some kind of authentication to the server then give the key back to the client then.  Packaging it is security issue as now everyone has your private keys.

Comment: But still the initial key exchange would be insecure right? Maybe I should post a new question on security.stackexchange.com ☺

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (correct solution)**

Finally! think I have understood what the comment meant

```
android {
  ...
  ...
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doLast {
      copy {
        from (["../client.private", "../server.public"])
        into ("$outputDir/raw")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Older solution (works but not an ideal one)**

I haven't been able to find a way to include individual files in the sourceSets so the next trick was to try copying the files to the `raw` folder

The solution is based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3femjd/including_your_readme_file_to_your_resource/) reddit thread

```
task copyKeyStores(type: Copy) {
    from files(["../client.private", "../server.public"])
    into 'src/main/res/raw'
}
tasks.copyKeyStores.execute()
```

**Note:** As per [one of the comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3femjd/including_your_readme_file_to_your_resource/ctoaoxo) in the reddit thread, there is a better way but I am [unable to figure it out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34650444/206292).

Comment: `variant.mergeResources` throws "API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'." Any solutions?

Answer (score 9):

EDITED

Please try to use `sourceSets`. (Path edited)

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['../client.private','../server.public']
    }
  }
}
```

You can check path each assets directories.

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs.each{println it}
}
```

Comment: Don't think its possible to include files directly under 'srcDirs'.

Comment: Thought of using 'include' in 'soueceSets' but looks like its not supported by android plugin http://stackoverflow.com/a/25184988/206292

Comment: Thanks but 'assets.srcDirs' accepts only paths to folders, not individual files.

Comment: I had misunderstood..Can you put these files to directory?

Comment: I don't want to but looks like I may not have a choice.