# What is a 'resource-generating task' in Android Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3femjd/including_your_readme_file_to_your_resource/) reddit thread has a solution to one of my [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595582/android-gradle-how-to-include-assets-from-the-root-project) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3femjd/including_your_readme_file_to_your_resource/ctoaoxo) comment

> ...a better option is to create a task which copies the file into "$project.buildDir/readme/res/raw/", register that folder with the Android plugin as a generated resource root, and register the task with the Android plugin as **resource-generating task**.

seems to be suggesting a better way but I am not sure what is meant by 'register as a resource-generating task'.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what have you tried?

Comment: The solution in the thread is to copy the file to the 'src' directory which does work but the comment says it's better to copy directly to the build folder by registering as a resource generating task. This is what I am clueless about.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is stated in another stackoverflow question. Didn't want to duplicate it here...

Comment: Still not sure what your trying to accomplish.  Do you want to include a `README.txt` file in your apk/aar?  If so what is the goal? Just have the file exist inside the archive or do you need to reference it via java?  Please explicitly state what your trying to accomplish

Comment: I am trying to include a file from the root directory of my project into the apk file. Complete details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595582/android-gradle-how-to-include-assets-from-the-root-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, think it means registering to `mergeResources` task like below

```
variant.mergeResources.doLast {
    copy {
       from ("path/to/some/file")
       into ("$outputDir/raw")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They're probably referring to `variant.registerResGeneratingTask`. This doesn't appear to be publicly documented so it may be subject to change, but it is used by various third-party plugins such as [this one](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/04/27/victor/).