# Excluding files in the resource folder in Android gradle builds

Tags: android, templates, gradle

I am working on a project where we use a templating system to produce build-specific files.

It works by taking a file with the keyword `.template` somewhere in the name, processing it, and then outputting it to the filename it would have if the keyword was removed.

However, this seems to work bad with gradle. If i let the extension be xml, i get (as expected) errors explaining that my XML is not parseable, which makes sense as it has the templating syntax in it.

If i make the file end with `.template`, i get errors complaining that the file has to end with `.xml`:

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
[...]android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml.template: Error:The file name must end with .xml
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

I have tried excluding it in the grade build file, like this:

[Android Studio: Exclude resource file under resources sourceSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172731/android-studio-exclude-resource-file-under-resources-sourcesets)

but to no avail.

I tried doing this in the android block of my build.gradle:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude '*.template'
}
```

Without it doing anything.

I found a few other posts about doing similar things on the internet yesterday, but they all did it differently in some way, and some of them were many years old.

**Therefore, my question is, what is the easiest/best way to exclude all files containing `.template` at any position in the file name?** For my exact issue, the file lies in the resources folder, but a general, one size fits all solution would be great

Comment: did you tried to rename it to colors.template.xml and `exclude '*.template*'`

Comment: When doing that, i simply get the `the file must end with xml` error message, sadly :/

Answer (score 0):

Make your file starts with a dot.

If I have a file like:

```
fragment_dashboard.xml.backup
```

I recive the error: *the file must end with xml*

However if I rename the file to:

```
.fragment_dashboard.xml.backup
```

There is no error